# Strange .txt File Appeared on Desktop

Tags: files

A strange .txt file appeared on my desktop today. Technically, it seemed to have been created one day ago, but it was only recently that I discovered it. The following were its contents when I opened it up:

'ma
1 hour ago
No one'

And it was titled 'ma
1 hour ag'.

It may also be worth mentioning that it was hidden away beneath the Quick Launch Bar, which explains why I didn't notice it before, but I'm confused as to: a) Where did the file even come from, and b) When I tried to re-tuck it beneath the bar, it was literally impossible to do. So how did it end up there in the first place?

I'm real freaked out by the ominous tone of the text and would appreciate any help figuring out how this could have possibly happened. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding the placement of the file: when a file is getting placed on a desktop for the first time, its coordinates are calculated throughout the entire available area of the desktop. The quick launch bar's presence is likely no concern of the algorithm that places the desktop icons. That's how it could have ended up underneath it. Only the human interaction, the mousedrag is taking the bar into account, that's why there is a difference regarding what's possible for you with a mouse.

Comment: Looks to me like a cut/paste or redirection error, not nefarious activity.

Comment: delete the file and look if it happens again, may you create a file with that name of course unintentionally, that happens sometimes by me if i use the mkdir command for e. `hello world` i have 2 folders `hello` and `world` because it must be `mkdir "hello world"`

Comment: @Levente That's valuable insight, thank you! And yes, it does seem to me as well to be some kind of copy/paste error, but I genuinely can't remember ever having copied that.

Comment: Do you use a browser extension that has some functionality like selecting and using text (for sharing, usually?) from web pages?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like part of a comment from a blog or social media site was copy/pasted.

For example, a comment like this might have been partially highlighted then copied to the clipboard.

```
Emma
1 Hour ago
No one cares, dude.
```

Highlighting text is very easy to do accidentally, as is copying to clipboard and pasting. All it takes is mouse button clicks. Text files can also be created with the right-click menu. It could happen by accident, especially if children or pets are around.

Comment: The cat ran through my keyboard! It caught my mouse! They copied all the files!

Comment: Which program is the one that upon saving a file whose file-name field was left empty, uses the first 12 characters (I counted the newline as 1) from the text body as file name, instead of the usual string "Untitled"? Possibly a browser extension?

Comment: The default file name would not be "untitled" In ubuntu when creating a text file on the desktop using right-click menu. The only thing it asks for is the file name and you can paste clipboard text containing newlines for the file name.

Comment: That's how it works on Lubuntu. Ubuntu might be different.